# Who owes who money?

Tags: code-golf

The Dank Memes Casino is one of the best casinos of the world. They have a rule that if you win or lose money, you will be paid at the beginning of the next month.

But, catastrophe struck and there was an earthquake, which demolished the casino.

Now, all the poker players have gathered and realised that the casino is not the person that owes them money or they do not owe the casino money, but as a matter of fact, they owe each other!

Your mission, should you choose to accept, will be to find out who owes who money.

Also, do keep in mind that the shortest code wins.

### Input

The first line contains the names of the people separated by spaces (Let there be n names).

The second line contains n integers, the ith of which denotes the ith person's winnings or losings at poker. A positive number means that he is owed money from someone, whereas a negative number entails that he owes someone money.

Flexible input methods are accepted.

### Output

Print out as many lines as required.
Each line should contain the name of the person who owes the money, the name of the person who is owed money, the amount of money that is owed separated by a space.

### Input Constraints

2 <= n <= 6

-100000 <= amount of money <= 100000

### Guaranteed Constraints

Sum of all integers in the array = 0

## Sample Test Cases

### Test Case 1

Sample Input

```
Messi Ronaldo Hazard Ibrahimovich
1000 1000 -2000 0
```

Sample Output

```
Hazard Messi 1000
Hazard Ronaldo 1000
```

### Test Case 2

Sample Input

```
Maradona Pele 
20000 -20000
```

Sample Output

```
Pele Maradona 20000
```

### Test Case 3

Sample Input

```
A B C D E
1 1 1 1 -4
```

Sample Output

```
E A 1
E B 1
E C 1
E D 1
```

### Test Case 4

Sample Input

```
A B C D E F
3 3 1 2 -4 -5
```

Sample Output

```
F D 2
F C 1
F B 2
E B 3
E B 1
E A 3
```

### Clarification

There may be multiple answers, anyone of them will be accepted.
For example:

```
A B C
1 1 -2
```

can yield both of the following:

```
C A 1
C B 1
```

or

```
C B 1
C A 1
```

both are correct.

Comment: What if multiple people have debts? Do the payments need to be equally distributed?

Comment: The sum of all debts is equal to 0, so if multiple people have debts, they will owe someone else in the group of people

Comment: What if it's `A: 2, B: 2, C: 2, D: -3, E: -3`? Also, does input have to be that strict?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino- look at test case 4. I just added it. also, how else do you want to take input?

Comment: Typiclly, we allow for much more relaxed input; in this case, normally we would allow to take input as key-value pairs in the language's implementation; normally, functions are allowed in place of programs. Ultimately it's the challenger's decision but that's typically what happens.

Comment: Your fourth test case does not clarify the exact algorithm used. Is it attributing debt to the most in-debt person first and filling in some particular order?

Comment: I see no issues with making the input flexible.
And coming to your test case,
A B C D E
2 2 2 -3 -3
will yield
E C 2
E B 1
D B 1
D A 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61017/discussion-between-koishore-roy-and-hyperneutrino).

Comment: `No negotiation on the output format.` -1, most competitive entries will want to return a list of strings from a function

Comment: @StephenS you can read HyperNeutrino's comment above. The input output is upto the challenger. It's not about what most people want. I made the input flexible, but doing that to the output will in some cases ruin the basic readability. So if you have to give a -1, that's totally on you. Don't pin this on most competitive entries.

Comment: "readability" ...This is Code Golf. "Readability" is meaningless here.

Comment: I hope the strictness in outputs are just discouraged not completely boycotted, otherwise there would be no meaning of specifiying output requirements.

Comment: @officialaimm for code-golf, a good challenge will specify what the data is (truthy/falsey, an number, a string, a list), not the format ("true" or "false", "must have 0 before `.` even if your language doesn't", "must be strings separated by newlines, cannot return a list")

Comment: Oh, I see. that makes sense. Thanks @StephenS

Comment: There's some notion of "standard forms of output" and an array of strings (as opposed to displayed characters) tends to be an accepted format. I can't find the meta post on it at the moment.

Comment: I removed the strictness on the output format. Feel free to output in any format as long as it is understandable

Comment: Some meta posts about string output. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7371/47990 https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2456/47990 https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2453/47990 (those second two are the same question and there's some other useful answers there too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 146 bytes

```python
def f(p,b):
	a=sorted(zip(b,p))
	while a:
		d,D,c,C=a[0]+a[-1];t=d+c;a[0]=(t,D);a[-1]=(t,C);a=a[t>=0:[len(a),-1][t<=0]]
		if d:print D,C,min(-d,c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7BToUwEDzDV/RGm7ckhacXak0UJHrw4rXpoVAITXjQQKPx/Twu4GF2Jzuzk/G/YZinfNts15OeemhYEUdGrvMSOkvvztMGPGNx9DO4sSMG1chCBS2U0iiuL0almRZB2ksr9oOkASomjvPOS@ToDM@SF2rsJmoYoKTCk@RaY5rriS384qZAKijh5iaaWmjZUak@K5FT9@LcjfjvKk4hjmuqks9uXV0Cydc8mdHOyN7N3SwWyUezmMHd5m/XDokGojLOORwjzffJNTsyXtD8iigRFeINUeOHusIVMsghfYD0Ec3bHw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 173 bytes

```python
a=lambda:input().split()
m={x:int(y)for x,y in zip(a(),a())}
l=lambda k:m[k]
while any(map(l,m)):d=min(m,key=l);s=max(m,key=l);t=min(m[s],-m[d]);m[d]+=t;m[s]-=t;print(d,s,t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7NCsIwGLvvKb5jP@wEnV42evD3JcYOlU0s69eVteKq@Oy1Q8FDEpIQiA3@NpgiRim0pEsrS2Xs3TNcOqtV0ozEa0qhZwGvwwgTD6AMPJVlkiFPwHemf2PoS6r7JnvclO5AmsBIWqY5IZatIGUY8b4LQmPlBMnpb/23rV3Dc6rbBquZF8JXc5YnteN8ouWOe4xxB3s4wBFOcM4KKGAFa8g3kG8/)

-6 bytes thanks to ppperry using dictcomps instead of `dict` of a listcomp

Comment: You can save five bytes by converting the second line to a dictcomp: `m={x:int(y)for x,y in zip(a(),a()))}`

Comment: @ppperry I did not know that works :o thanks!

Comment: @HyperNeutrino has anyone ever told you how awesome you are?

Comment: @KoishoreRoy hm?